Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Service not available
I'm encountering an issue while trying to send emails from my .NET application using the SmtpClient class. Even though my credentials are correct, I keep getting the following error:

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: Service not available

Sometimes, after multiple attempts, I also get a timeout error.
What I've tried:

Verified that my SMTP server (smtp.gmail.com) is correct and the port is set to 587
Confirmed that my username and password are accurate
Enabled SSL based on the configuration settings
Made sure that less secure apps are allowed in my Gmail account settings

Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Below is the relevant code snippet:
public class EmailService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<EmailService> _logger;
 
    public EmailService(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<EmailService> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }
    
    public async Task<EmailResponse> SendEmailAsync(EmailRequest emailRequest)
    {
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(emailRequest.Sender);
            foreach (var recipient in emailRequest.Receipient)
            {
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
            }
            mailMessage.Subject = emailRequest.Subject;
            mailMessage.Body = emailRequest.Body;
    
            var configurationKeys = _configuration.GetSection("EmailConfig").Get<EmailConfig>();
            if (configurationKeys == null)
            {
                _logger.LogError("No email credentials available.");
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configurationKeys), "No email credentials                    available.");
            }
    
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            {
                Port = 587,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configurationKeys.Username, configurationKeys.Password),
                EnableSsl = configurationKeys.EnableSSL?.ToLower() == "true",
            };
    
            try
            {
                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                _logger.LogInformation("Email sent successfully.");
                return new EmailResponse { Status = "successful", Message = "Email sent                successfully." };
            }
            catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
            {
                _logger.LogError(smtpEx, "SMTP error occurred while sending email.");
                return new EmailResponse { Status = "failed", Message = smtpEx.Message };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while sending email.");
                return new EmailResponse { Status = "failed", Message = ex.Message };
            }
        }
    }
}


You could try this below code:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace EmailSenderProject
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set up configuration and logging
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole())
                .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .Build())
                .BuildServiceProvider();

            var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
            var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();

            var emailService = new EmailService(configuration, logger);

            var emailRequest = new EmailRequest
            {
                Sender = "sender address",
                Receipient = new[] { "receiver address" },
                Subject = "Test Email",
                Body = "This is a test email sent from a .NET application."
            };

            var response = await emailService.SendEmailAsync(emailRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Message);
        }
    }

    public class EmailService
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        private readonly ILogger<Program> _logger;

        public EmailService(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Program> logger)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public async Task<EmailResponse> SendEmailAsync(EmailRequest emailRequest)
        {
            using (var mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(emailRequest.Sender);
                foreach (var recipient in emailRequest.Receipient)
                {
                    mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
                }
                mailMessage.Subject = emailRequest.Subject;
                mailMessage.Body = emailRequest.Body;

                var configurationKeys = _configuration.GetSection("EmailConfig").Get<EmailConfig>();
                if (configurationKeys == null)
                {
                    _logger.LogError("No email credentials available.");
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configurationKeys), "No email credentials available.");
                }

                using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"))
                {
                    smtpClient.Port = 587; // Make sure the port is 587 for TLS
                    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false; // This should be false since you are providing credentials
                    smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configurationKeys.Username, configurationKeys.Password);
                    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true; // Ensure SSL is enabled

                    try
                    {
                        await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
                        _logger.LogInformation("Email sent successfully.");
                        return new EmailResponse { Status = "successful", Message = "Email sent successfully." };
                    }
                    catch (SmtpException smtpEx)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(smtpEx, "SMTP error occurred while sending email.");
                        return new EmailResponse { Status = "failed", Message = smtpEx.Message };
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while sending email.");
                        return new EmailResponse { Status = "failed", Message = ex.Message };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class EmailRequest
    {
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public string[] Receipient { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmailResponse
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmailConfig
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string EnableSSL { get; set; }
    }
}

And make sure you have enabled 2FA on google account you are using and set up the app password.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833
appsettings.json:
{
  "EmailConfig": {
    "Username": "sender email",
    "Password": "app password",
    "EnableSSL": "true"
  }
}



Yep, the issue is not from the code, but has to do with security, because my endpoint is http when I send the email, it fails when deployed and make the request where it has a valid https endpoint it goes through successfully.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
